# How to create a looping RACSignal with RACScheduler

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa, racsignal

Is there a way to create a scheduled RACSignal that emits value every interval of time ?

I'm wondering if there is a way other than creating a dispatch timer ? or some kind of for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is! I think you're looking for [`interval:onScheduler:`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/2b7c6d37b47cf5d1773fc354aa84882bf9cc39e3/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L339). It will emit the current `NSDate`, which is usually not that useful, so you can use it to sample another signal that has the data you want. For example, with a constant value:

```
[[RACSignal return:@20] sample:[RACSignal interval:1.0
                                       onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]];
```

Edit:

...or you could just `mapReplace` that...

```
[[RACSignal interval:1.0 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]] mapReplace:@20];
```

If you want to perform a calculation every time the interval ticks, and you don't have that as another signal, you can use a normal `map` that ignores its argument.

```
[[RACSignal interval:1.0 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]] map:^(id x) {
    return ...
}];
```

Comment: func dummySignal() -> RACSignal {
        return RACSignal.createSignal({ (sub:RACSubscriber!) -> RACDisposable! in
            let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            timeFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
            sub.sendNext(timeFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))
            return nil
        })
    }
    func currentTimeSignal() -> RACSignal {
        return dummySignal().sample(RACSignal.interval(1, onScheduler: RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler()))
    }

Comment: I've created a new dummySignal using RACSignal.createSignal and i'm calling sample on it, but it seems to fire only once ...

Comment: @EdwardAshak I'm not sure what you mean by "fire only once." The `sample` will only subscribe to the underlying signal one time, so `currentTimeSignal` should be a signal of the same string over and over. If you want to calculate something on each tick, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks @Ian Henry, mapReplace should do the trick. Thanks for your help